# What kinds of differential equations were solved on the early differential analyzer?

Tags: differential-equations

Harold Locke Hazen and Vannevar Bush created the Differential Analyzer at MIT between 1928 and 1931 to solve differential equations, according to the [Wikipedia Article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_analyser). I've read this other places as well. But the only differential equations I've ever read about being solved are those for artillery.

What other kinds of differential equations were solved?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0016003227916706 - V. Bush and H.L. Hazen, Journal of the Franklin Institute 204(5) 575-615 (1927) - has a long description of the machine and a variety of problems of second order total differential equations to illustrate the operation.